# Usefulness of let?

Tags: lisp

Is the distinction between the 3 different let forms (as in Scheme's let, let*, and letrec) useful in practice?

I am current in the midst of developing a lisp-style language that does current support all 3 forms, yet I have found:

1. regular "let" is the most inefficient form, effectively having to translate to an immediately called lambda form and the instructions generated are nearly identical. Additionally, I haven't found myself needing this form very often.
2. let* (sequential binding) seems to be the most practically useful and most often used. This form can be translated to a sequence of nested "lets", each environment storing a single variable. But this again is highly inefficient, wasting space and lookup time.
3. letrec (recursive binding) can be efficiently implemented, given that no initializer expression refers to an unbound variable. Typically the case is that all initializers are lambda expressions and the above is true.

The question is: since letrec can be efficiently implemented and also subsumes the behavior of let*, regular let is not often used and can be converted to a lambda form with no great loss of efficiency, why not make default "let" have the behavior of the current "letrec" and be rid of the original "let"?

Answer (score 4):

> This [`let*`] form can be translated to a sequence of nested "lets", each environment storing a single variable. But this again is highly inefficient, wasting space and lookup time.

While what you are saying here is not incorrect, in fact there is no need for such a transformation. A compiling strategy for the simple `let` can handle the semantics of `let*` with just simple modifications (possibly supporting both with just a flag passed to common code).

`let*` just alters the scoping rules, which are settled at compile time; it's mostly a matter of which compile-time environment object is used when compiling a given variable *init* form.

A compiler can use a single environment object for the sequential bindings of a `let*`, and destructively update it as it compiles the variable *init* forms, so that each successive *init* form sees a more and more extended version of that environment which contains more and more variables. At the end of that, the complete environment is available with all the variables, for doing the code generation for generating the frame and whatnot.

One issue to watch out for is that a flat environment representation for `let*` means that lexical closures captured during the variable binding phase can capture future variables which are lexically invisible to them:

```
(let* ((past 42)
       (present (lambda () (do-something-with past)))
       (future (construct-huge-cumbersome-object)))
  ...))
```

If there is a single run-time environment object here containing the compiled versions of the variables `past`, `present` and `future`, then it means that the `lambda` must capture that environment. Which means that although ostensibly the `lambda` "sees" only the `past` variable, because `future` is not in scope, it has *de facto* captured `future`.

Thus, garbage collection will consider the huge-cumbersome-object to be reachable for as long as the `lambda` remains reachable.

There are ways to address this, like accompanying the environmental reference emanating from the `lambda` with some kind of frame index which says, "I'm only referencing part of the environment vector up to index 13". Then when the garbage collector traverses this fenced reference, it will only mark the indicated part of the environment vector: cells 0 to 13.

Anyway, about whether to implement both `let` and `let*`. I suspect if Lisp were being "green field" designed from scratch today, many designers would like reach for the sequentially binding version to be called `let`. The parallel construct would be the one available under the special name `let*`.  The situations when you actually need `let` to be parallel are fewer. For instance, `let` allows us to re-bind a pair of variable symbols such that their contents appear exchanged; but this is rarely something that comes up in application programming. In some programming language cultures, variable shadowing is frowned up on entirely; GNU C has a `-Wshadow` warning against it, for instance.

Note how in ANSI Common Lisp, which has `let` and `let*`, the optional parameters of a function behave sequentially, like `let*`, and this is the only binding strategy supported! So that is to say:

```
(lambda (required &optional opt1 (opt2 opt1)) ...)
```

Here the value of `opt2` is defaulted from whatever the value of `opt1` is at the time of the call. The initialization expression of `opt2` has the `opt1` parameter in scope.

Also, in the same Lisp dialect, the regular `setf` is sequential; if you want parallel assignment you must use `psetf`, which is the longer name of the two.

Common Lisp already shows evidence of design decisions more recent than `let` tend to favor sequential operation, and designate the parallel as the extraordinary variant.

Comment: the parallel variant help me when reading code because it indicates that the introduce variables are independant;

Comment: @coredump I would say that it makes code harder to read because it breaks the rule "to find the definition of an identifier being referenced, just search backwards from that point in the file". Under `let`, a reference to some `X` does not necessarily go to the textually most recent definition, but possibly to a prior one. Code that you're reading is not necessarily correct: if you have `(let ((a (foo)) (b (+ a (bar))) ...)` you know that `a` and `b` are independent; but is that the **intent**? Maybe that `a` was meant to go to the textually most recent definition.

Answer (score 1):

Think of metaprogramming. If your default let will sequentially create nested scopes, you'll have to make sure that none of the initialiser expressions are referring to the names from the wrong scopes. You have such a guarantee with a regular let. Control over name scoping is very important when you're generating code.

Letrec is even worse, it's introducing a very complicated scope rules that cannot be easily reasoned with.